# Why can't I cd to a root owned folder, as a member of the root group?

Tags: linux, permissions, unix, root

I verified I'm a member of `root`:

```
user_me@host1:~$ sudo useradd -G root user_me
useradd: user 'user_me' already exists
```

However, I can't `cd` to `/root/testing` from my user:

```
user_me@host1:~$ cd /root/testing
-bash: cd: /root/testing: Permission denied
```

If I `sudo su -` into root, I can verify that the folder I'm trying to cd into is owned by `root`, and has appropriate permissions.

```
user_me@host1:~$ sudo su -
Last login: Tue Sep 22 00:23:07 CDT 2015 on pts/1
[root@host1 ~]# ll | grep testing
drwxrwxr-x  2 root root      135 Sep 22 00:20 testing
```

Comment: The first command did not verify what you claim it does, instead please provide the output of `id user_me` .

Comment: You;ve shown that the `testing` directory (please don't call it a folder! This is not windows) is accessible, however you've not shown that the same is true for `/root`.

Answer (score 2):

Because you need the `x` bit set on all descending directories in the tree, to the target one, to be able to cwd through'em. I suppose `/root` hasn't one for the root group, it's probably 0700.

Comment: Agree. If it won't work provice ls -la output.

Answer (score 0):

For checking own groups your need use command:

```
groups *username*
```

For access in directory your need set bit x in permission group